# How to identify which beacon is exiting, beacon notification seen when beacon is out of range

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am trying to detect beacon devices using my device, and so monitoring them and also listening to the range notifications.

I am using [this](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) library and the library-reference app. I managed to listen to a custom beacon using the set beacon layout method.

Step1. I set the layout in the application class
Step 2. I mke the baseactivity implement beaconconsume where it performs ranging.

When starting the range monitoring service/method we use "myRangeUniqueId" but the didexit and didenter methods use "backgroundId" I think. Why is that so?

So the situation is this
I move the beacon device some few meters away , I still get I see a beacon notification and I do not see a beacon.. These messages keep changing alternatively even when the beacon is far.

Do I have to do anything to prevent this? Please help.

the code snippets include below:

1. The application class implements BootstrapNotifier and the code is as under

   ```
   BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
   beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("LAYOUT_HERE"));

   Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
           null, null, null);
   regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

   // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
   // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
   // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
   backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);



    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
         // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
       Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
       if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
           Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");
           haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
       } else {
           // i am not sending out any notification here since there could be multiple beacons and i need to identify any one of them with a specific uuid
       }


   }


   @Override
   public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
       sendNotification("exited",2);
   }
   ```

i do nothing in `didDetermineStateForRegion` method,its just overridden

2. I have a `BaseActivity` that implements `BeaconConsumer`

   ```
       private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           beaconManager.bind(this);
      }

       @Override 
       protected void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           beaconManager.unbind(this);
        }
       @Override 
       protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
                 if(beaconManager.isBound(this))beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
            }
    @Override 
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(false);
     }

      @Override
      public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
         beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override 
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
               if (beacons.size() > 0) {
               /*EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                       .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
               Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
               logToDisplay("The first beacon "+firstBeacon.toString()+" is about "+firstBeacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");    */
       CommonUtilities.sendNotification(BaseActivity.this,"entered",1);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   });

   try {
       beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId",null, null, null));
       } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
     }
   ```

P.S: When i move the device to a different location say some 5 meters away, i get random notification, that the beacon is in range and then immediately i get a notification that the beacon is out of range.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. The unique identifier is used as a key to identify a `Region` so you can start and stop ranging and monitoring.    Each region you construct and register with the system should have a different string identifier, but the value can be whatever you wasn't so long as it is unique.
2. The `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback is made every second, and not just when a mobile device enters range of the beacon.
3. If you are getting repeated `didExitRegion` callbacks when the beacon is within 20 meters or so, you may have a beacon that is not transmitting frequently enough.  Knowing the beacon make, model and transmission frequency as well as your mobile device model might help solve this.

Comment: I changed the new Region string to `new Region("keyhere",Identifier.parse(uuidhere)),null,null);` . Yes the beacon is within 20 meters of range, and so to prevent the entry and exit calls frequently, i changed the timeout in MonitorState to 20000l instead of 10000l, which i know is not appropriate, and the scan freq to 2000l as per [this](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/27)

Comment: We are using april beacon, i am afraid i donot know the transmission freq :(.

Comment: In case the April beacon is transmitting at < 1Hz, you can try reducing the scan frequency to see if the didExitRegion calls stop.  The following code reduces the scan frequency in the foreground to 30 seconds from the default of 1.1 seconds:  `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(30000l);`

Comment: hi sir, i reduced the scan frequency to 2000, and i have tested it, if at all the exit call comes in i could try 30 seconds too. But will this affect how beacons are detected?

Comment: but i have even increased the timeout period from 10s to 20s. I am doing it the correct way?

Comment: Yes,  this will affect the frequency of the ranging callbacks if you set it successfully. Make sure you but this line before you set up your RegionBootstrap.

Comment: sir, yes, thats where i put in the scanning time (foreground)... i am marking this as the ans :). And +1 for all your time.. If there is anything, i will get back to you..